# Closing an iframe after it has reloaded another html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have made the following site:

[www.ppp.one](http://www.ppp.one)

Whenever you open an image, a popup is loaded.

This popup can be closed using the `X` on the top-right. However, if you click on one of the thumbnails in the popup (reloading the frame) the `X` button can no longer close it.

The JavaScript I use:

```
function hide(){

    if(currentIframe){
        currentIframe.hide();
        currentIframe = null;
    }

    popupBG.remove();
    popup.remove();
}
```

And the html:

```
<a class="small align-top" onclick="frameWarp.hide();">&#10006</a>
```

Any ideas on what is causing the issue?

Comment: `Uncaught ReferenceError: frameWarp is not defined` is what is thrown in the console.

Comment: It seems like, whenever the `iframe` is reloaded, the `frameWarp` becomes `undefined`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you open the popup you call a function `setUpAPI` which inserts the `frameWrap` object into the global scope of the iframe. 
When a thumbnail is clicked the frame is reloaded and the `frameWrap` instance is no longer available.

You could try listening for `load` events on the iframe instead of `ready` events:

```
iframe.ready(function(){
  frameCacheDiv.append(iframe);
});
iframe.load(function(){
  setUpAPI(iframe, settings);
  settings.onShow();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! Where should I be placing this? I keep getting errors when I try to implement it. (I have never done JavaScripting in detail before!)

Comment: Just replace `ready` with `load` in line 127 of http://www.ppp.one/framewarp/framewarp.js

Comment: I just changed it and the frame no longer loads! :(

Comment: It looks like the `load` event does not fire when the iframe is not in the DOM. The `append` call therefore has to stay in the `ready` handler. I'll update the answer in just a second.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like when the iframe's URL changes the frameWarp variable becomes undefined. One idea to try would be to listen to the load event of the iframe and make your changes there: (you'd have to give it the ID of "iframeId")

```
$('#iframeId').load(function(){
    console.log('URL changed');
    // code to attach hide event here
});
```

Another idea would be to change your setup to use the postMessage API for the communication between the parent and iframe. You can read a tutorial of how to do that here:

http://robertnyman.com/html5/postMessage/postMessage.html

Edit: Actually, this blog post is a better example: http://davidwalsh.name/window-iframe

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response too. I can't quite see how to implement the id through the javascript? Or is it done else where?

Comment: You should be able to do it through javascript. One way to check would be to do:

console.log( $("#iframeId").length );

And if its 0 it's not being set, if its 1 it is being set.

Comment: also, in case you were talking about setting the id itself. You can do that like this: iframe.attr("id","iframeId"); (where iframe is a jquery object). You can also set it manually on the iframe tag when you create it.

Comment: Lastly, I'd highly recommend switching to using the postMessage API for this. It'll make your code cleaner and easier to maintain in the future.